# Carrierwave testing - clean up or separate file uploads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, carrierwave

I'd like some feedback and/or help please.

I'm having this test

```
scenario 'can create a new post' do

    attach_file('Image', 'spec/files/hello-world.png')
    fill_in 'Caption', with: 'Hello World! This is the first post!'
    click_button 'Create Post'

    expect(page).to have_css("img[src*='hello-world.png']")
    expect(page).to have_content('Post was successfully created')
end
```

This test uploads the image to `uploads/post/image/1/hello-world.png` through Carrierwave, which is probably the same path on development environment etc, so I wonder if this is going to cause any issues on between files and posts.

My question is do I need to keep separate the file uploads on each Environment, or is it something that Rails can manage internally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location where the files are stored is [defined in a Carrierwave Uploader by the method `store_dir`](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory). If you need to separate the files created in different environments, the simplest solution is to add `Rails.env` to the path:

```
def store_dir
  @store_dir ||= File.join(
    'public',
    'uploads',
    Rails.env,
    model.class.table_name.to_s,
    mounted_as.to_s,
    model.id.to_s   
  )
end
```

This will create a path like: `public/uploads/production/posts/image/1/image.png`

Comment: Do I also have to change and the `cache_dir` too? Also how can I clean the `uploads/test/` from any files when finishing tests? something similar to what `database_cleaner` does on the database records

Comment: The last question is optional, as I have added the `uploads` folder in the gitignore

Comment: For the file tidy up, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352062/rails-carrierwave-testing-how-to-remove-file-after-test It's rspec specific, but shouldn't be that difficult to use similar techniques with minitest.

Comment: "Do I also have to change and the cache_dir too?" - Yes

Comment: Can you please share the code to test the Carrierwave uploader as well.

Comment: @sagarverma I'm afraid that's not possible five years after the answer was posted. I haven't touched carrierwave for years.